# Python: Aaccess a function within another class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to access a function within another class, and doing that going through a "master" class.  I have successfully accessed the "master" class through the Column 4 button, I'm trying to access the master class through the column 5 function, and then make that go to the reaction function in the window class, however when I try this, it fails.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window():
    def __init__(self, parent, parent_class2):
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent_class = parent_class2
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.parent, width=420, height=360)
        self.canvas.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand="true")
        self.cellwidth = 60
        self.cellheight = 60
        self.rows = 6
        self.columns = 7
        self.rect = {}
        self.oval = {}
        self.piece = []
        #creates the grid
        for row in range(6):
            for column in range(7):
                x1 = column*self.cellwidth
                y1 = row * self.cellheight
                x2 = x1 + self.cellwidth
                y2 = y1 + self.cellheight
                self.piece.append(Piece(self.canvas, x1,y1,x2,y2))

        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.piece[8].oval, fill="deep pink")

    def reaction(self):
        print("In WIndow Class - SUCCESS!")

class ButtonsExampleGUI:
    def __init__(self, parent, parent_class):

        self.parent_class = parent_class
        self.parent = parent
        #self.buttons = 7

        c4 = Button(parent,text = ("Column 4"), command = self.c4_played)
        c4.pack(side = LEFT)
        c5 = Button(parent,text = ("Column 5"), command = self.c5_played)
        c5.pack(side = LEFT)


    def c4_played(self):
        self.parent_class.test()
        print("Col 4")

    def c5_played(self):
        print("Col 5")
        self.parent_class.towindow()

class Piece:
    def __init__(self, parent_canvas, x1,y1,x2,y2):
        self.parent_canvas = parent_canvas
        self.rect = self.parent_canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2, fill="grey", tags="rect")
        self.oval = self.parent_canvas.create_oval(x1+2,y1+2,x2-2,y2-2, fill="white", tags="oval")

#self class here is being taken as the "parent_class" of the ButtonExampleGUI class
class Game:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.window = Window (self.parent, self)
        self.buttons = ButtonsExampleGUI (self.parent, self)

#test being accessed by c4 function calling this within a different class
    def test(self):
        print("from parent class")

    def towindow(self):
        print("In Game Class")
        self.parent_class2.reaction()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    game = Game(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about the specific way this is failing? If there is an exception can you provide that as well?

Comment: @eric-scrivner Here's the error 'Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:\2015 DTS\3.46\C4 Revisions\4May.py", line 77, in c5_played
    self.parent_class.towindow()
  File "H:\2015 DTS\3.46\C4 Revisions\4May.py", line 109, in towindow
    self.parent_class2.reaction()
AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'parent_class2' '

Comment: Should class Game extend tkinter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe because you didn't define parent_class2 in Game? Try changing def towindow(self):

from:

```
def towindow(self):
    print("In Game Class")
    self.parent_class2.reaction()
```

to:

```
def towindow(self):            
    print("In Game Class")
    self.window.reaction()
```